# NSBundle cant find my plist file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, plist

I dont't know why in one of my project, program can find `plist` file without any problem and in another file it returns nil.

It drives me crazy.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("poi", ofType: "plist")
```

[image]

you can see in debugger that this variable is nil

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe is not included in the `Copy Bundle Resources`. Did you check that? I notice that sometime drag and drop files wasn't automatically included.

I tested it that it work when is in the `Copy Bundle Resources` and it return nil if it wasn't included but still is a file in the project.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, i am pretty sure it was checked to copy when i was dragging file. Anyway it sorted the issue! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check your `plist` file is added inside `Copy Bundle Resources` inside `Build Phase`. Check image for more detail

[image: 1]]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but Zac was faster so i marked his answer as correct. Thank you agsin